# How to use gcc or git without installing xcode?

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode

I am a newbie of Mac user. I can see there are `gcc`, `git`, etc in the "`/usr/bin`" folder. But when I want to use them,  it prompts like this:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ nan$ git
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command   line developer tools.
MacBook-Pro:~ nan$ gcc
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
```

Does it mean I must install `xcode` to use `gcc` or `git`, thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I don't know osx, but it seems that `/usr/bin/git` calls `xcode-select` which gives the error, so `/usr/bin/git` may be just a wrapper that selects from installed developer tools versions. See FILES section of https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html

Comment: Do you really need gcc or just a C/C++ compiler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you don't, at least not anymore. The possibility mentioned by @jherran involves installing yet another piece of software. If that's ok with you, you can use Hombrew or Macports. Its controversial which one is 'better', so take which one you like.

But, since OSX Yosemite (or maybe earlier, not sure), the Command Line Tools can be installed separately, which is great since it allowed me to ditch the huge useless XCode app sitting idly on my hard drive.
The most straightforward way might be to simply download the right package from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

When issuing the commands you mentioned, does a window pop up prompting you to install the Command Line Tools? It is outlined [here](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) that this is what should happen.

Or, just try to run

```
xcode-select --install
```

Which should do what you want. They can be updated via the App store, at least on Yosemite.

Note that if the executables are present in `/usr/bin`, you should be able to call them with their full name, e.g. `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: :Other link:[Install command line developer tools in OS X](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-in-os-x/)

Comment: In El-Captain it doesn't matter whether you run git or /usr/bin/git. It pops up this dialog and asks me to install..

Comment: Yes I just installed with Homebrew -- using the command git still prompts an Xcode install

Answer (score 6):

You could install both of them using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install gcc
brew install git
```

To install homebrew, you just need this single command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Anyway, if you want to use git and gcc installed on you system, you don't need to install Xcode, instead you just need to install the **command line developer tools**, that you can install by typing:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Why there are `gcc` or `git` in "`/usr/bin`"? They are not executable files? Why can't use them directly?

Comment: Both tools exists but are outdated. Git on yosemite is on version 1.9.3, homebrew version is 2.2.0. Anyway, you don't need to install Xcode, just need the command line developer tools, and you can install by typing `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why tools which outdated can't be used? Could you explain or give some links about it? Thanks!

Comment: Are outdated, but of course you can use it. But, in order to work you need the command line developer tools, don't know why, but it's a fact.

Comment: Hombre needs command line tools which include a C/C"" compiler and git - so hombre does not give you anything for just those